# Draw 2 imline to be perpendicular to each other matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to constraint the the imline to be always perpendicular to the other imline drawn on the same object. for ex. I draw a first line using "imline" now I want to draw second line across the first line to be perpendicular to it. if there is a way to force the second imline to be perpendicular to the first line keeping the flexibility of extending the length  it will solve my problem some extent.
I want something like a flexible cross hair(which can rotate along the axis and have flexible sides) on my image to measure the height and width of the certain object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
function perpline()

    imshow(rand(200),[]);

    line1 = imline(gca,[50 50; 150 150]);
    setColor(line1,'r');
    line2 = imline(gca,[50 150; 150 50]);
    setColor(line2,'g');

    addNewPositionCallback(line2,@(pos)callback_line(pos));

    function callback_line(pos)
        % Must update line1 based on line2's position
        pos_line1 = getPosition(line1);
        pos_line2 = getPosition(line2);

        % Get middle
        pos_center = [(pos_line2(1,1)+pos_line2(2,1))/2 (pos_line2(1,2)+pos_line2(2,2))/2];

        % Find displacement
        vec_disp = [pos_line2(2,1)-pos_line2(1,1) pos_line2(2,2)-pos_line2(1,2)];

        % Get normal unit vector
        vec_perp = [-vec_disp(2) vec_disp(1)]/norm(vec_disp);

        % Preserve length of line2
        length_line1 = norm([pos_line1(2,1)-pos_line1(1,1) pos_line1(2,2)-pos_line1(1,2)]);

        pos_line1_update = [-vec_perp*length_line1/2+pos_center;
                            vec_perp*length_line1/2+pos_center];

        % Set position
        setPosition(line1,pos_line1_update);                
    end
end
```

Save it as a function then call it. You can drag the green line around and the red line remains perpendicular. Note that you have to define how you want it to preserve the perpendicularity. I chose to preserve the length of the red line and keep it in the center of the green line.

[image]

Comment: Hi jucetain,thank you very much I will try this , this definitely looks what i wanted.

Comment: How can I get the position back once I done resizing the line, I cannot double click and exit out, is there a way to get the position or distance of the two end point back

Comment: In `callback_line` you could use `disp` on the position. Or, you could have the function return a handle to the line and then use `getPosition` on it whenever you want the updated position.