# How to find an arbitrary perpendicular vector of another vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, geometry

I need to create arbitrary perpendicular vector n with components (a, b, c) to another known vector k with components (x,y,z).
The following code creates arbitrary vector n, but I need random numbers for components in the range [-inf, inf] how can I acheive that? (because otherwise vector components created may not exceed some value in given case 10^11 ) Or maybe concept "arbitrary vector" does not require that?

```
function [a,b,c] = randomOrghogonalVector(x,y,z)
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
randomDistr = rand * 10^11 * 2 - 10^11; % issue 1
% excluding trivial solution
if x == 0 && y == 0 && z ==0 
    a = NaN;   b = a;   c = a;
else
    if z ~=0
        a = randomDistr;
        b = randomDistr; 
        c = - (x * a + b * y ) / z;
    else
        if z == 0 && x ~= 0
            c = randomDistr;
            b = randomDistr; 
            a = - (z * c + b * y ) / x;   
        else
            if z == 0 && x == 0 && y ~= 0
                c = randomDistr;
                a = randomDistr; 
                b = - (z * c + a * x ) / y;   
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Find a vector whos dot product with the one you have is equal to zero.

Comment: You can also use the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) where the second vector has unknown components, then you can substitute any two values (`x,y`, `x,z`, or `y,z`) and solve for the other unknown to complete what you want.

Comment: Thank you, but how to make it arbitrary?

Comment: "substitute any two values" == arbitrary

Comment: Not very well defined, as the position and length of the vector will not be specified, only the angle will. However, if you specify that it should be the in the middle of the input vector with the same length, then it is well defined. I have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141891/draw-2-imline-to-be-perpendicular-to-each-other-matlab/24142990#24142990) that you can reference and take a look at.

Comment: @JohnSmith : have I answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I see is to first find a random vector that is orthogonal to your original vector, and then give it a random length. In Matlab, this can be done by defining the following function

```
function [a, b, c] = orthoVector(x, y, z)
    xin = [x;y;z];
    e = xin;
    while ((e'*xin)==xin'*xin)
        e = 2.*rand(3,1)-1;
    end
    xout = cross(xin, e);
    xout = 1.0/(rand()) * xout;
    a = xout(1);
    b = xout(2);
    c = xout(3);
end
```

Line-by-line, here's what I'm doing:

1. you asked for this format `[a,b,c] = f(x,y,z)`. I would recommend using `function xout = orthoVector(xin)`, which would make this code even shorter.
2. Since Matlab handles vectors best as vectors, I'm creating vector `xin`.
3. `e` will be one random vector, different from `xin` used to compute the orthogonal vector. Since we're dealing with random vectors, we initialize it to be equal to `xin`.
4. For this algorithm to work, we need to make sure that `e` and `xin` are pointing in different directions. Until this is the case...
5. ...create a new random vector `e`. Note that rand will give values between 0 and 1. Thus, each component of `e` will be between -1 and 1.
6. Ok, if we end, `e` and `xin` are pointing in different directions
7. Our vector `xout` will be orthogonal to `xin` and `e`.
8. Let's multiply vector `xout` by a random number between 1 and "very large"
9. `a` is first component of `xout`
10. `b` is second component of `xout`
11. `c` is third component of `xout`
12. all done.

*Optional*: if you want to have very large vectors, you could replace line 8 by

```
xout = exp(1./rand())/(rand()) * xout;
```

This will give you a very large spread of values.

Hope this helps, cheers!